# Android Positioning Progress Dialog or Custom Progress Dialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

I don't know how to position the progress dialog(the one with the rotating image). When my application starts its display an full screen image and a progress dialog box. I need to moved the progress dialog box a little lower.

Thanks
Rajesh

Comment: you can set offset from the edge. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14018725/779408

Answer (score 5):

I've tried this one and works:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do a similar thing and I found that it was just easier to build a class that extends Dialog that shows the image and the Progress spinner.

Comment: Thanks. I did the similar thing. I just need the spinner when I start the app. So I added progressbar in my layout. 
  <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="135px"
   android:layout_y="360px"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dip" />