# How to change the position of a progress dialog?

Tags: android, position, alignment, progressdialog

I'm developing an android app and need to know how to change the positioning of a progress dialog. I need it to be positioned at the bottom of the screen instead of at the center like it is by default.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can call `ProgressDialog#getWindow#setGravity(...)` to change the gravity.

So:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(AContext, "Test", "On the bottom");
                dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Answer (score 19):

In addition to the other answers you can use LayoutParams.x or LayoutParams.y to provide an offset from the given edge. For Example:

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Title","Text");

progressDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
LayoutParams params = progressDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
params.y = 100;
progressDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

And it is good for you to know about LayoutParams.y:

> Y position for this window. With the default gravity it is ignored.
>   When using TOP or BOTTOM it provides an offset from the given edge.

and about LayoutParams.x:

> X position for this window. With the default gravity it is ignored.
>   When using LEFT or START or RIGHT or END it provides an offset from
>   the given edge.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information.  I don't need it today, but I will in the future.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using any custom theme for the ProgressDialog, Then you could add the below xml tag to the style in your style.xml file of the custom theme

`<item name="android:layout_gravity">bottom</item>`

Answer (score 1):

Adding android:gravity="bottom" to the outermost XML element in the layout might do it. Not sure if this moves the dialog or the contents of it.

Comment: This won't bring the dialog to the bottom of the screen. It can move the content to the bottom of the parent view.